# Distribution related to brownian bridge

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, brownian-motion, uniform-distribution

Let $B(t)$ be a Brownian Bridge and $U$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. I wish to know the distribution function $B(U)$. Is it possible? As we know, $B(t)\sim N(0,t(1-t))$. But, I haven't a clue when $t$ is replaced by random variable $U$. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Empirically the distribution of $B(U)$ seems to have a variance of $\frac{1}{6} = \displaystyle \int_0^1 t(1-t)\;dt$ which is what I would expect. $B(U)$ seems to be more leptokurtic than a normal distribution with the same variance (though less so than a logistic distribution)

Comment: Is $U$ independent of the Brownian bridge?

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yes. $U$ is independent with $B$

Comment: I agree with Henry that it will be more leptokurtic since quite probable to t's close zero or one which will have result from distributing normals very "squeezed towards 0" thus resulting in a high cluster of samples being near zero.

Comment: I also found this which you may also find interesting   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution

Comment: Thanks @user159813 for the reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p_t$ denote the PDF of $B(t)$ and assume that $U$ is independent of $B$ with PDF $f_U$, then the distribution of $B(U)$ has PDF 
$$
q(\ )=\int p_t(\ )f_U(t)\mathrm dt.
$$
In the present case, $U$ is uniform on $(0,1)$ and, for every $t$ in $(0,1)$,
$$
p_t(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi t(1-t)}}\mathrm e^{-x^2/(2t(1-t))},
$$
hence
$$
q(x)=\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi t(1-t)}}\mathrm e^{-x^2/(2t(1-t))}\mathrm dt.
$$
The change of variable $4t(1-t)=1/u^2$ yields
$$
q(x)=\frac2{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-2x^2(1+u^2)}\frac{\mathrm du}{1+u^2}.
$$
Differentiating this and identifying $q'(x)$ yields finally

> $$
> q(x)=2\int_{|x|}^\infty\mathrm e^{-2u^2}\mathrm du.
> $$

Note that, to compute some characteristics of the distribution of $B(U)$, one may find more convenient to bypass the PDF $q$ and to go back to the definition of $B(U)$, for example,
$$
E(B(U))=\int_0^1E(B(t))\mathrm dt=0,
$$
and
$$
E(B(U)^2)=\int_0^1E(B(t)^2)\mathrm dt=\int_0^1t(1-t)\mathrm dt=\frac16.
$$
Likewise, for every suitable measurable function $A$,
$$
E(A(B(U)))=\int_0^1E(A(B(t)))\mathrm dt=\int_0^1\int_\mathbb RA(x)p_t(x)\mathrm dx\mathrm dt.
$$

Comment: Thanks @Did for your help. Very nice analysis. +1

Answer (score 1):

This may be completely wrong but its just an idea

So any distribution is characterized by its CDF $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$ well to determine this for a distribution $X\sim B(U)$, what $P(X\leq x)$ would if $U$ was a discrete uniform $S=\{\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{4},\frac{3}{4}\}$ letting $\Phi_{t}(x)$ represent CDF for $N\left((0,t(1-t)\right)$ would be 
$$F(x)=P(X\leq x)=\sum_{t\in S}P(X\leq x |U=t)P(U=t)=\frac{1}{3}\left(\Phi_{\frac{1}{4}}(x)+\Phi_{\frac{2}{4}}(x)+\Phi_{\frac{3}{4}}(x) \right)$$

Thus my guess for if $U\sim Uni(0,1)$ then the CDF for $B(U)$ would be 
$$F(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\Phi_{t}(x)dt$$

again this is a naive guess

even if this doesn't look like it pertains to a specific known distribution I think you can still simulate from this distribution using following code in R

> rB=function(size,lower.bound,upper.bound)
>
> {
>
> sample=NULL
>
> for(i in 1:size)
>
> {
>
> U=runif(1,lower.bound,upper.bound)
>
> BU=rnorm(1,mean=0,sd=sqrt(U*(1-U)))
>
> sample[i]=BU
>
> }
>
> return(sample)
>
> }

I also assumed that when you write $N(0,t(t-1))$ that $\sigma^{2}=t(t-1)$

Comment: It makes sense. So, we cannot identify using some known distribution, can we?

Comment: You can use a test functino $\psi$ and conditional expectations to show rigourously your result : $\mathbb{E}[\psi(B(U))]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\psi(B(U))|U]]$ given the density of $B(U)$ which would be $\Phi_U'(x)$ (roughly)

Comment: Good thing is you can still simulate from this distribution still by simulating a random uni I,1 variable then inputing that in B(t) formula then simulating from a normal with that parameter. Would be a pretty easy function to write in R if what I said is correct

Comment: Do you guess $B(U)\sim N(0,t(t(1-t)))$?

Comment: Oops my bad just edited it silly mistake

Comment: Also I was wondering is it true letting $F(x)$ be CDF for rvX $g(t)=1_{X<t}$ that $F(t)=E[g(t)]$

Comment: @Jlamprong what do you mean by guess B(U)? Also I meant to say random uni 0,1

Comment: @user159813: I am sorry, my question about $B(U)$ is for Henry. Sorry, for not mentioning him

Comment: @user159813: Thanks for your help. And also for the R code. I know nxt to nothing about R. Could you tell me, what the distribution after getting an intuitive thing from R?